# Unity script not doing anything, but dont get any errors either

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, 2d

Hey guys I'm pretty new to unity and coding in general but I've really tried to figure out why this script does not apply. The idea of the script is that is is supposed to spawn an object on a random location on the X-axis within the range +9 to -9 repeatedly, but it just spawns once at the start location of the object. Hope someone can point me in the right direction :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnOnXaxis : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Goodfood;
public int numToSpawn;
public Vector3 position;

void Awake()        
{
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F), 10.5f, -1); // -9 på Xaxis - +9 ----- Y = 10.5 z = -1
}

void Start() 
{
    int spawned = 0;

    while (spawned < numToSpawn)
    {

        position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F), 10.5f, Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F));

        GameObject tmp = Instantiate(Goodfood, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; // Quaternion.identity betyder "ingen rotation"

        spawned++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting numToSpawn to anything. Try this:

```
public class SpawnOnXaxis : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Goodfood;
public int numToSpawn;
public Vector3 position;

void Awake()        
{
    position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F), 10.5f, -1); // -9 på Xaxis - +9 ----- Y = 10.5 z = -1
    numToSpawn = 10;
}

void Start() 
{
    int spawned = 0;

    while (spawned < numToSpawn)
    {

        position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F), 10.5f, Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F));

        GameObject tmp = Instantiate(Goodfood, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; // Quaternion.identity betyder "ingen rotation"

        spawned++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It made no difference :/ still nothing happens beside the one spawn on game start

Comment: Is the Awake() function being called? Try setting numToSpawn to for example 10 when you declare it: public int numToSpawn = 10;

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
[Invoke Reapeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) can solve your problem.
The code below calls CreateObjects ever 0.3 seconds. Firstly 1 second later it start.

```
public GameObject Goodfood;
public int numToSpawn;  //I assume you edit this value in editor
public Vector3 position;
int spawned = 0;
void Start() // or you can use Awake too.
{
    InvokeRepeating("CreateObjects", 1, 0.3);
}

void CreateObjects(){
     position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F), 10.5f, Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F));
     GameObject tmp = Instantiate(Goodfood, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
     spawned++;
     if(spawned>9){
        CancelInvoke("CreateObjects");
     }
}
```

If you don't want use this, maybe you can use [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) method. Like

```
 void Update() {
     if(spawned<10){
         position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F), 10.5f, Random.Range(-9.0F, 9.0F));
         GameObject tmp = Instantiate(Goodfood, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
         spawned++;
     }
 }
```